# For the discrete topology, why must the singletons be in every basis?

Tags: general-topology

I know the set of all singletons are a basis for a discrete topology, but if we had another basis, why must it also include all the singletons?

Comment: Hint: how can you write a singleton as a union of other sets?

Comment: It is the union with itself, or do you mean it is impossible?

Comment: ok i got it now .

Answer (score 4):

Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, a *basis* for $(X,\tau)$ is a collection $\mathcal B \subseteq \tau$ such that for each $U \in \tau$ and each $x \in U$ there exists $B \in \mathcal B$ with $x \in B \subseteq U$. So, if $\tau = \mathcal P(X)$, for each $x \in X$ there exists $B \in \mathcal B$ with $x \in B \subseteq \{x\}$. It follows that $B = \{x\}$ is in $\mathcal B$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the following lemma:

Lemma: Let $X$ be a space and $\mathbb{B}$ a basis for $X$. $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if for each $p\in U$, there exists some $B\in \mathbb{B}$ such that $p\in B\subseteq U$.

Indeed, if $X$ is a topological space endowed with the discrete topology, then every singleton is open. Hence by the preceding lemma, any basis for the topology of $X$ must contain all the singletons. A consequence of this is, if $X$ is uncountable and discrete then $X$ is not second countable.

Comment: If $X$ is uncountable and discrete, then it _isn't_ second countable.

Comment: Yes. I shouldn’t have used “may be”. But id argue my point was clear provided the context.

Comment: Okay.  I knew what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

That's the only way to get the singletons to be open.  That is, suppose we have a basis $\mathcal B$ such that for a certain $x$, we have $\{x\}\not\in\mathcal B$.  Then $\{x\}$ isn't open, and the topology isn't discrete.

The key seems to be as @HallaSurvivor points out:  a singleton can't be written as the union of proper subsets.